# Testing a new version of an installed android app?

Tags: android, package, signing

I've been working on some updates to an existing application I have in Google Play. The newer version of the application makes some changes to the application database.  The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how best to test the new update. Eclipse signs my "devel" package with debug.keystore (I presume) while the installed application from GP was signed with my release.keystore so I get the error message "Re-installation failed due to different application signatures” when I try to "run" my changes within Eclipse for debugging.

It's weird because I can download the 'release' apk from my company website and side-load it. This seems to ignore the signing even though the apk from GP and the one side-loaded are the same file.

If I go into Eclipse's Windows > Preferences > Android > Build and enter my release.keystore in under "custom debug keystore" (to get around the key signing descrepency) then Eclipse just complains the "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" so that route is out as well.

I'd really like to be able to test a 'real world' update before pushing the new apk to GP.  Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the apk signed with your release key and use `adb install -r myapp.apk` to update it on a device that has the older version installed.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a way to integrate with Eclipse, but this works fine.

Comment: Integrating with Eclipse is not doable without a hack. If you want to automate it, you can use Ant and have a task that builds, exports, signs and install on the devices.